# Ledger Nano X causing error when running sugar PLEASE HELP very Aggravating!

Tags: wallet, cli, keypair

i keep getting this errror ive used sugaR BEFOR BUT NOT WITH A HARDWAQRE WALLET If anyone can hellp me out that would be awesome? error under arrow
|
|
\ /
v

**Error running command (re-run needed): Failed to read keypair file: usb:ledger?key=0, The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. (os error 123)**